# NodeJS 14+ use RC4-MD5 cipher algorithm with tls native package

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, ssl, encryption

I'm working on a project and i need to open **tls socket between NodeJS server and a device** (http server embedded on electronic card, which operates on a [PIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PIC_microcontrollers)).

This device only support **RC4-MD5** encryption algorithm but it's deprecated since Node 9 (I currently working on **Node 14.17.5**)

How can i implement **RC4-MDR5** algorithm in NodeJS **without downgrade** my node version ?

My code actually:

```js
const tls = require('tls');

let tlsOpts = { // TLS options
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('dist/assets/cert/privkey.pem')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('dist/assets/cert/cert.pem')),
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  ciphers: 'RC4-MD5' // This line throw error: SSL routines:SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list:no cipher match
};

this.server = tls.createServer(tlsOpts, async (socket) => { // Create server
  socket.setEncoding('utf8');
  this.events(socket); // Create event listeners (data, error, close, etc...)
}).listen(this.config.get('TCP_PORT'), () => {
  this.logger.log('TCP server started (port '+this.config.get('TCP_PORT')+')'); // Log server start
});
```

Edit: To go further, how can i implement my own encryption algorithm and use it with the node tls package ?

Ex:

```js
let tlsOpts = { // TLS options
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('dist/assets/cert/privkey.pem')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve('dist/assets/cert/cert.pem')),
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  ciphers: 'My-Custom-Cipher' // Here use my custom algorithm
}
```

*Note: I'm using NestJS framework, that why i have the syntax "this.[...]" in my code.*

Thanks.